# ie11 : input with numbers only

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I need my input to accept only numbers.
I have :

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

It works if I start typing letters, input will be emptied when it lost focus, but if I type "2blah" it will not be emptied.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Allows only [0-9] number, numpad number, arrow,  BackSpace, Tab, Del as wel as Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V, Ctrl + A.
Allow only one dot.
Remove if last char is dot on a blur event.

```
element.on('keydown', function(e) {
    var arrowsKeyCodes = [37, 38, 39, 40];
    var numPadNumberKeyCodes = [96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105];
    var dots = [110, 190];
    var tabBackDel = [8, 9, 46];
    var acv = [65, 67, 86];

    // Allow only one dot.
    if (e.target.value.indexOf('.') !== -1 && dots.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // allow only [0-9] number, numpad number, arrow,  BackSpace, Tab, Del
    // Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V, Ctrl + A
    if (
        (e.keyCode < 48 &&
            arrowsKeyCodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) === -1 || e.keyCode > 57 &&
            numPadNumberKeyCodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) === -1 &&
            dots.indexOf(e.keyCode) === -1
        ) &&
        tabBackDel.indexOf(e.keyCode) === -1 &&
        (e.ctrlKey === false || e.ctrlKey === true && acv.indexOf(e.keyCode) === -1)
    ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

element.on('blur', function(e) {
    var value = e.target.value;
    if (value.substring(value.length - 1) === '.')
        e.target.value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1)
});
```